# Count of Files in a Directory With Count of Files in Sub Directories Also Reported

Tags: dos

I want the DOS command to find the count of files in a given directory (the count should have separate entries for the sub directories under this directory).

For eg, if Tech is a directory and it has 2 files, and 2 sub-directories (Info Tech, Services), and the sub-directories have 2 files each, the my result should look like

```
Tech 6
Info Tech 2
Services 2
```

It would be great if someone could help me with such a command line...

Comment: And if Services also has two sub-directories with 2 files each, then Services should show 6 and Tech would now have 10?

Comment: yes dbenham. It should also print the count of those two sub directories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirements are not clear.

I'm assuming that for each folder you want the total number of files in the folder, including files in the sub-folders (recursive). You want to do that computation for the root folder, as well as all sub-folders (recursive).

This code works on all versions of Windows from XP on. I'm not sure if it works on true MS-DOS. Are you really using MS-DOS?

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1"=="" (call :recurse ".") else call :recurse %1
exit /b

:recurse
setlocal
set fileCnt=0
for /d %%D in ("%~1\*") do call :recurse "%%~fD"
for /f %%A in ('dir /b /a-d "%~1\*" 2^>nul ^| find /v /c ""') do set /a fileCnt+=%%A
echo "%~f1"  %fileCnt%
( 
  endlocal
  set /a fileCnt+=%fileCnt%
)
exit /b
```

The code lists the folders with file count from the bottom up. If you want the folders listed top down, then simply sort the results. Assuming the batch script is named fileCnt.bat, then

```
fileCnt | sort
```

Comment: Awesome dbenham.. Thanks so much for helping me out here.

Comment: It works on Windows NT 4 and the next ones (Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7 etc) since it requires the cmd.exe command interpreter. Previous Windows versions (Me, 98, 95) and the plain MS-DOS have only the command.com interpreter which does't understand command extensions like SETLOCAL.