# Get sum of all files' size in a directory in CMD

Tags: cmd

How can I get sum of sizes of all files which are located in a directory (but exclude files in subdirectories)?

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702326/count-of-files-in-a-directory-with-count-of-files-in-sub-directories-also-report)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `dir` command, the total bytes is displayed in the next to the last line. You could use:

```
dir | findstr "File(s)"
```

To get only this information for the current directory. Or

```
dir path | findstr "File(s)"
```

to get total size in the given path, for example:

```
dir c:\windows | findstr "File(s)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in MS DOS: But this doesn't exclude the sub folders and hidden files ;)

Try:

```
dir /a/s
```

Result in : Files for current directory and subdirectories wih their hidden files.
And total size for all of them.

[image]

PS: Frankly, there's a GUI you can get the folder size and number of files within. Curious to know why you want to do so within DOS? ;)

Comment: I need to use it in batch script:)

Answer (score 0):

This information is included in the output of the dir-command. In the line before the last output line is the number of files and the tortal size displayed.